# Where is the Delphic Expanse?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

What is the location of the Delphic Expanse? It doesn’t appear on any maps that I’ve seen, and the Xindi homeword is only 50 light-years away from Earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (non-canon, but still unsurpassed) [Star Trek: Stellar Cartography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1477805974) gives us an indication of both the location and scale of the Delphic Expanse, which lies approximately 50 light years from Earth, proximate to Regulus and Yridia

[image]

If we plot this location on a wider map of the Alpha quadrant from [Star Trek: Star Charts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743437705), you can see that the expanse lies relatively near the borders of both Romulan space (in green) and Klingon space (in red).

[image]

Comment: Nice work.  I assume the blue patch is Federation space (given the starbases, for instance), and so the Delphic Expanse is now Federation territory?

Comment: @Praxis - Yes, the blue area is Federation Space. We know from various sources that had the Xindi not been influenced against Earth, that they would have become a member of the Federation in good standing by the 24th Century.