# Is there any evidence to suggest Q has a mechanism of travel similar to the Spore drive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q, star-trek-discovery, spore-drive

In the *[Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek): [Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery)* Episode *[Context is For Kings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings_(episode))*, we see the [Spore Drive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spore_drive).

> Their research was based on the insight that at a quantum level, there was no difference between biology or physics, and specifically that spores were not only the progenitors of panspermia, but also the building blocks of energy across the universe. This allowed Stamets and Straal to approach physics as biology. As such, the equations involved were reminiscent of both quantum astrophysics and biochemistry. (DIS: "Context Is for Kings")

The point being that the Spore drive appears to allow near [instantaneous travel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/81324/140) across the Galaxy.

Similarly the [character Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_(species)) appeared to have [godlike powers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q), including the ability to [instantaneously travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122378/161) across the universe.

The following commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/mervtwit/status/917519160137142278):

> **AfterTrek spores "Q" like travel capabilities Hhmm**

My question is: **Is there any evidence to suggest Q has a mechanism of travel similar to the Spore drive?**

Comment: Since we don't know how Q travels we have no idea. It could be he completely *moves the universe around him* giving the illusion of travel.

Comment: This is Small-Universe Thinking.

Comment: I always took Q as moving out of space and time (thus via a different dimension), while the spore drive.....being the forerunner to the transwarp drive (would make sense in that timeline.....although I wouldn't have thought they were THAT far at that stardate already)

Comment: As Q usually appeared in a flash (IIRC), he may not (need to) travel, but simply change physical location at will and *be there*, or even just *instantiating* a physical shape in that moment, displacing the air molecules been there before which would explain the ionization-like effekt.

Comment: @Murphy - Or he pops into the Q Continuum where time/distance work differently and just walks there or whatever.

Comment: *"there was no difference between biology or physics"*   What?

Comment: @JohnP And whenever. However, the result would probably look all the same from this/the ST side of the continuum: like magic.

Comment: At this time, there is really no evidence for anything at all except exactly what we've seen on screen., which is not enough to go on. If anything, the scene where Burnham first exposed to the "imaging" capability of the spore drive is reminiscent of the Iconian Gateways. Even there, however, there is no actual evidence that the spore drive is actually related to anything at all that we've ever seen before.

Comment: At least visually, Q's travel is more reminiscent of Warp Drive (that flash is the same effect as the Ent-D's warp), though clearly he doesn't actually use a Warp field to move.

Comment: Although this idea does have me hoping for John DeLancie to pop up in the background a few times as an easter egg, and then maybe save them before removing all of the Spore Drive knowledge "It's for your own good. At least wait a century or two will you?"

Comment: I have no evidence but think that Q can move in another dimension altogether, similar if not same to the inhabitants of the wormhole in DS9. I think any relationship might be similar in nature as  car travel is to boat travel, or baking is to cooking.

Comment: @Murphy: Q was omnipresent, he didn't need to do anything as mundane as "travel" as he's always everywhere anyway, he simply manifests an avatar to interact with Picard.

Comment: Nothing in canon that I'm aware of indicates that Q is omnipresent.

Comment: I don't recall seeing Q spinning around at the waist before a entrance/exit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No.

There is not the slightest evidence that Q's powers are somewhat related to the Spore Drive. Some random guy's twits don't really count, I fear.

---

Q, both as a single individual as portrayed by John De Lancie, and as a whole species, are featured prominently on *The Next Generation*, and also make some appearance on *Deep Space Nine* and *Voyager*.

In all these appearances, they are always shown to posses godlike powers, like yourself are acknowledging in your questions. **Going instantly in any given point of the galaxy is among these powers, but it is certainly not the only one**: they can change their appearance at will, they can time-travel, they can transport other beings (even whole starships) trough time and space without effort, and trick you in many other ways if you let them:

[image]

Briefly, we can summarize all of this by saying that **physics laws are not constraining them at all**, and that with their powers they can effectively do whatever they please. The origin of their powers is never described in detail but it is implied that they possess them inherently, not as the result of an incredibly advanced level of technology; and, **more to the point of your question, it is never stated, suggested or even subtly implied that they use a spore network to travel.**

**We know that Spore Drive is a FTL method that just allows incredibly fast speeds, it does not completely suspend all physics laws for its users. So, it can't be accounted to be the source of all other Q powers, and it is highly improbable that they, having godlike powers in all other respects, are constrained to use a physical mean just to travel.**

Comment: The Q have limits so I don't see any evidence that they aren't bound by the laws of physics. Everything they do is achievable with tech in the star trek universe in a more limited way. Even voyager entering the continuum using just tech. +1 for the rest though its more like a fast long range temporal transporter like the timeship relativity uses than spore drive